# Как получить точку, лежащую на грани эллипса?

Tags: c#, wpf

Мне нужно соединить 2 эллипса линией. Нужны координаты точек граней, чтобы потом нарисовать стрелку. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Кхм, кхм, что такое - грань эллипса?

Comment: Касательную к двум эллипсам провести, что ли? ну реши систему уравнений, аналитически, получишь все 4 касательные.

Comment: @Igor Завуалировал линию фигуры так) У круга - окружность, к эллипсу некорректно говорить окружность)

Comment: @Akina Не касательную, именно соединить 2 эллипса. Это можно сделать соединив их центры линией, но мне надо чтобы линия не пересекала эллипс

Comment: *соединить 2 эллипса ... соединив их центры линией ... чтобы линия не пересекала эллипс* Тебе самому не видна бредовость идеи - соединить точки (одна внутри, другая снаружи эллипса) отрезком так, чтобы он не пересекался с эллипсом???

Comment: @Akina Было бы неплохо, если бы вы читали полностью моё сообщение. Ни один эллипс не должен быть пересечен

Comment: Покажите мне то место вопроса, где написано, что центр одного эллипса лежит внутри другого эллипса.

Answer (score 3):

Берем каноническое уравнение эллипса:

```
x^2 / a^2 + y^2 / b^2 = 1
```

Избавимся от дробей:

```
x^2 * b^2 + y^2 * a^2 - a^2 * b^2 = 0
```

Оси такого эллипса всегда совпадают с осями системы координат, равно как и центр эллипса с началом координат.
Сдвинем эллипс куда-нибудь в сторону, добавив к иксу и игреку смещения dx и dy соответственно.

```
dx > 0 – влево, dx < 0 – вправо.

dy > 0 – вниз, dy < 0 – вверх.

(x + dx)^2 * b^2 + (y + dy)^2 * a^2 - a^2 * b^2 = 0
```

Теперь центр эллипса может быть где угодно, но его оси по-прежнему параллельны осям системы координат. Добавим поворот на угол A с помощью оператора поворота (одно из аффинных преобразований):

Выполним замену:

```
X = cosA * x – sinA * y

Y = sinA * x +sinA * y
```

С учетом смещений:

```
X = cosA * (x + dx) – sinA * (y + dy)

Y = sinA * (x + dx) + sinA * (y + dy)


X ^2 * b^2 + Y ^2 * a^2 - a^2 * b^2 = 0
```

В громоздком и страшном виде:

```
(cosA * (x + dx) – sinA * (y + dy)) ^2 * b^2 + 
+ sinA * (x + dx) +sinA * (y + dy) ^2 * a^2 - a^2 * b^2 = 0
```

Нарисуем эллипс, у которого большая полуось a=4, малая полуось b=3, смещение по оси абсцисс dx=-5, по оси ординат dy=-3, и который повернут на 45 градусов против часовой стрелки (45 гр = pi/4 = 0,785):

```
(cos(0.785) * (x + (-5)) – sin(0.785) * (y + (-3))) ^2 * 3^2 + 
+ sin(0.785) * (x + (-5)) + sin(0.785) * (y + (-3)) ^2 * 4^2 - 4^2 * 3^2 = 0
```

Проверить можно тут: https://math.semestr.ru/line/ellipse.php

Ближе к делу:

Имеем два эллипса. Координаты их центров – (dx1, dy1) и (dx2, dy2) соответственно.
Проводим линию, соединяющую центры эллипсов:

```
y = k * x + b

y = (dy2 – dy1) / (dx2 – dx1) * x + b

dy1 = (dy2 – dy1) / (dx2 – dx1) * dx1 + b

b = dy1 - (dy2 – dy1) / (dx2 – dx1) * dx1

y = (dy2 – dy1) / (dx2 – dx1) * x + dy1 - (dy2 – dy1) / (dx2 – dx1) * dx1 = 
= [(dy2 – dy1) / (dx2 – dx1)] * (x - dx1) + dy1
```

Теперь задача в том, чтоб найти точки пересечения данной линии с эллипсами. Найдя две точки, можно будет программно провести линию «от и до».

Для 1-го эллипса (для 2-го – по аналогии):

```
(cosA * (x + dx1) – sinA * (y + dy1)) ^2 * b^2 + 
+ sinA * (x + dx1) + sinA * (y + dy1) ^2 * a^2 - a^2 * b^2 = 0

y = [(dy2 – dy1) / (dx2 – dx1)] * (x - dx1) + dy1
```

Подставляем 2-е уравнение в первое, и получаем уравнение от одной неизвестной x:

```
(cosA * (x + dx1) – sinA * ([[(dy2 – dy1) / (dx2 – dx1)] * (x - dx1) + dy1] + dy1)) ^2 * b^2 + 
+ sinA * (x + dx1) + sinA * ([[(dy2 – dy1) / (dx2 – dx1)] * (x - dx1) + dy1] + dy1) ^2 * a^2 - a^2 * b^2 = 0
```

Решив, получим икс. Подставив икс в любое из 2-х уравнений выше, найдем ординату точки. Всё.

Как решать такое уравнение? Можно поискать красивое аналитическое решение, но мне лень. Можно реализовать решение численным методом, но это вряд ли хороший вариант, если требуется частая перерисовка изображения – всё может сильно тормозить.
Если же повороты эллипсов не требуются, то:

```
(x + dx1)^2 * b^2 + (y + dy1)^2 * a^2 - a^2 * b^2 = 0

y = [(dy2 – dy1) / (dx2 – dx1)] * (x - dx1) + dy1

(x + dx1)^2 * b^2 + ([(dy2 – dy1) / (dx2 – dx1)] * (x - dx1) + dy1 + dy1)^2 * a^2 - a^2 * b^2 = 0
```

Введем обозначения:

```
p = (dy2 – dy1) / (dx2 – dx1)

c = a^2 * b^2

(x + dx1)^2 * b^2 + (p * (x - dx1) + 2 * dy1)^2 * a^2 - c = 0

(x + dx1)^2 * b^2 = x^2 * b^2 + 2 * x * dx1 * b^2 + dx1^2 * b^2

p * (x - dx1) + 2 * dy1 = p * x - p * dx1 + 2 * dy1

m = p * dx1 - 2 * dy1

p * (x - dx1) + 2 * dy1 = p * x – m

(p * (x - dx1) + 2 * dy1)^2 * a^2 = p^2 * x^2 * a^2 - 2 * p * x * m * a^2 + m^2 * a^2
```

Итого:

```
x^2 * b^2 + 2 * x * dx1 * b^2 + dx1^2 * b^2 +
+ p^2 * x^2 * a^2 - 2 * p * x * m * a^2 + m^2 * a^2 – с = 0
```

Это ни что иное, как квадратное уравнение:

```
(x^2 * b^2 + p^2 * x^2 * a^2) + (2 * x * dx1 * b^2 - 2 * p * x * m * a^2) + (dx1^2 * b^2 + m^2 * a^2 – с) = 0

x^2 * (b^2 + p^2 * a^2) + x * (2 * dx1 * b^2 - 2 * p * m * a^2) + (dx1^2 * b^2 + m^2 * a^2 – с) = 0

A = b^2 + p^2 * a^2
B = 2 * dx1 * b^2 - 2 * p * m * a^2
C = dx1^2 * b^2 + m^2 * a^2 – с

x^2 * A + x * B + C = 0
```